# Empty String in C

Tags: c, string

I wrote a function to tokenize a mathematical expression. It seems to be working almost fine, except for one thing: the first token has a garbage value at its beginning. I start by declaring variable currentToken to "", then I append new chars to it as the function expression is processed. When a token is complete, I allocate memory for it again and set it to "" again. The whole idea seems to be working, except for the first token.

The code for the tokenization function and some related parts follows:

```
/* Returns a list of strings (tokens) that make up the infixString: */
ListOfStrings tokenize_infix_str( const char *const infixString )
{
    ListOfStrings tokens;
    char *currentToken = "";
    char currentChar;
    int i;
    int lengthOfInfixString = strlen( infixString );

    initialize_list_of_strings( &tokens );

    for ( i = 0 ; i < lengthOfInfixString ; ++i )
    {   
        currentChar = *( infixString + i );

        if ( ( currentChar != ' ' ) && ( currentChar != '\t' ) && ( currentChar != '\n' ) )
        {
            currentToken = append_ch_to_str( currentChar, currentToken );

            if ( i <= lengthOfInfixString - 2 )
            {
                if ( ( global_array_contains_token( "allFunctions", currentToken ) ) ||
                    ( global_array_contains_token( "allOperators", currentToken ) ) ||
                        ( ( ( strcmp( currentToken, "(" ) ) == 0 ) ||
                            ( ( strcmp( currentToken, ")" ) ) == 0 ) ||
                                ( ( strcmp( currentToken, "x" ) ) == 0 ) ) ||
                                    ( ch_is_part_of_number( currentChar ) &&
                                        !ch_is_part_of_number( *( infixString + i + 1 ) ) ) )
                {
                    insert_at_end_of_list_of_strings( &tokens, currentToken );

                    currentToken = ( char * )malloc( sizeof( char ) );
                    currentToken = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ( ( global_array_contains_token( "allFunctions", currentToken ) )
                    || ( global_array_contains_token( "allOperators", currentToken ) )
                        || ( ( ( strcmp( currentToken, "(" ) ) == 0 )
                            || ( ( strcmp( currentToken, ")" ) ) == 0 )
                                || ( ( strcmp( currentToken, "x" ) ) == 0 ) )
                                    || ( ch_is_part_of_number( currentChar ) ) )
                {
                    insert_at_end_of_list_of_strings( &tokens, currentToken );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    free( currentToken );
    currentToken = NULL;

    //DEBUG:
    printf( "tokens from infix expression are:\n" );
    print_list_of_strings( &tokens );
    //ENDDEBUG

    return tokens;
}

/* Appends ch to str and returns the resulting string; returns NULL if an error occurs: */
char *append_ch_to_str( const ch, char *str )
{
    char *temp;
    int i;
    int tempLength;
    int strLength = strlen( str );

    if ( strLength != 0 )
    {
        temp = ( char * )malloc( ( strLength + 2 ) * sizeof( char ) );

        if ( temp == NULL )
        {
            return temp;
        }

        for ( i = 0 ; i < strLength ; ++i )
        {
            *( temp + i ) = *( str + i );
        }

        /* At this point, i equals strLength. */

        *( temp + i++ ) = ch;
        *( temp + i ) = '\0';  

        return temp;   
    }
    else
    {
        temp = ( char * )malloc( 2 * sizeof( char ) );

        *( temp ) = ch;
        *( temp + 1 ) = '\0';

        return temp;
    }
}

/* Returns str1 + str2, or NULL if an error occurs: */
char *append_str2_to_str1( char * str1, const char *str2 )
{
    char *newString = ( char * )malloc( ( ( strlen( str1 ) ) + ( strlen( str2 ) ) + 1 ) *
        sizeof( char ) );
    int i = 0;

    if ( newString != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( newString, str1, strlen( str1 ) );

        for ( ; i <= strlen( str2 ) - 1 ; ++i )
        {
            if ( ( str1 = append_ch_to_str( *( str2 + i ), str1 ) ) == NULL )
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        if ( ( str1 = append_ch_to_str( '\0', str1 ) ) == NULL )
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        return str1;
    }

    return NULL;
}

typedef struct listOfStrings {
    char **array;
    int numberOfElements;
} ListOfStrings;
```

How do I prevent this garbage value at the beginning of the first token?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?

Comment: I'm not experienced at debugging. I'm only printing the tokens on the screen.

Comment: For one, the current token should be initialized to NULL, not an empty string, and an input infix that is empty will quickly demonstrate that, as you'll be passing a read-only literal address to `free()` in said case. Also, your append function leaks memory, as you're never freeing the old buffer or using `realloc`, which I would recommend. And buried in that code is a blatant memory leak that allocates memory for a single char, then promptly overwrites that allocation result with the assignment to a string literal address, forever losing the allocation in the ether. *Debug this*.